# Using Autoprefixer (Grid) in Nuxt Project

Tags: nuxt.js, css-grid, tailwind-css, autoprefixer, gulp-autoprefixer

I am trying to start autoprefixer for grid in my Nuxt project. But unfortunately without success.

I have created a .browserslistrc and entered "default" there.

The nuxt.config.js:

```
        postcss: {
            plugins: {
                'postcss-import': {},
                'postcss-nested': {},
                tailwindcss: {},
                autoprefixer: {}
            },
            preset: {
                stage: 1,
                autoprefixer: {
                    grid: true
                }
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Solution:

```
        postcss: {
            plugins: {
                'postcss-import': {},
                'postcss-nested': {},
                tailwindcss: {},
            },
            preset: {
                stage: 1,
                autoprefixer: {
                    grid: true
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The "problem" is not written in the question.